# React Native: when should you call function in constructor vs componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, rendering, render

I know from reading [this article](https://blog.pusher.com/beginners-guide-react-component-lifecycle/) that the `contructor` is called pre-render, and `componentDidMount` is called post-render, but I don't understand how this influences how we decide which one to use. What happens during render that would make me want to call an initialization function before or after that render?

Answer (score 0):

Constructor is solid to initialize state variables, bind event handlers, and call super(props).

ComponentDidMount is when a component is mounted. It is where you want to set up DOM nodes, interact with browsers/API (ex: pulling data from MongoDB), and loading data elsewhere.